# How to check with only Jest if a child component gets rendered

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a happy path of testing in my parent component and it will render a component or p tag. I'm lost on How to test if that child component gets rendered. Here is my parent component.

```
if (startDate && endDate && startDate <= endDate) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      <DateRangeInput {...this.props} />
      <DateRangePicker
        startDate={moment(startDate)}
        endDate={moment(endDate)}
        onChange={this.onDatePickerChange}
        mode={DateRangePicker.MODE_RANGE}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
return (
  <div className={styles.root}>
    <DateRangeInput {...this.props} />
    <p>Cannot have start date after end date</p>
  </div>
);
```

Here are my tests. I'm not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way, or the best practice when it comes to testing an if statement

```
describe('<DateRangeInputPicker />', () => {
  it('should show null messaging when endDate < startDate', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(
       <DateRangeInputPicker
          startDate={new Date(2018, 0, 14)}
          endDate={new Date(2017, 1, 29)}
          onChange={jest.fn()}
       />
   );

  expect( getByText('Cannot have start date after end date')).toBeInTheDocument();
});

 it('should render DateRangePicker when endDate > startDate', () => {
   const { getByText } = render(
     <DateRangeInputPicker
       startDate={new Date(2018, 0, 14)}
       endDate={new Date(2017, 1, 29)}
       onChange={jest.fn()}
    />
  );


});
```

});

Comment: Could you update the question with info about any other jest-related packages you're using? I've used Jest with React but I'm not familiar with `getByText` or `toBeInTheDocument`.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider implementing [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jest.html) in your testing environment with Jest if you are planning to test the lifecycle of your component and how it renders according to updates.

This piece of code will test what you are trying to achieve. If you are not familiar with Enzyme, there are plenty of courses, tutorials and blog posts on the internet.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import DateRangeInputPicker from './DateRangeInputPicker';

describe('DateRangeInputPicker', () => {

    const component = shallow(<CreateTask />);

    describe('when endDate < startDate', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            // Any code here to make your component come to that condition
        });

        it('should show a message', () => {
            const message = component.find('p'); // would be better to use an id or class selector
            expect(message.text()).toBe('Cannot have start date after end date');
        });
    });
});
```

Anyway, I'll try to explain what you should do.

1. Mount your component using the Enzyme [shallow](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) rendering.
2. Make your component to meet the condition you are expecting. There are many ways to achieve this, you could access to [setState](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setState.md) to update the component state if you have those properties there.
3. Find the DOM node you are expecting using Enzyme's [find()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) method.